# Keeping field values if error occurs

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have seen some solutions for my problem, but I just don't know how to apply them.  I am going post part of my validation file because it is large.

```
if ($action == "submit" && ($member_submit == 0 || ($member_submit==1
   && $_SESSION['loggedin']==1))){

                   $frompage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

                   if($_POST['thumburl']=="http://")
                   $_POST['thumburl']="";

                   // Check to see if the user is trying to bypass your requirements, and if so, redirect them!
                   if ($_SESSION['nosubmit']==1){
                     $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> There was something wrong with your
   submission. Please try again later</div>";
                       header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
                       exit;        

                   }
                   // End Cheat Check

                   // Check to see if IP address is allowed to submit. If not, redirect!
                   if (ban_check("submit") == "banned"){
                     $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Cannot Add Submission At This Time</div>";
                       header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
                       exit;        

                   }
                   // End Ban Check

                   $submissiontime = time();
                   if (($submissiontime - $delay) <= $_SESSION['submission']){
                    $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Flood Control Initiated</div>";
                       header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
                       exit; 
                   }
       $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
               $contenttitle = clean_string($_POST['contenttitle']);
               $contentdescription = clean_string($_POST['contentdescription']);
               $contenturl = clean_string($_POST['contenturl']);
               $contenturl2 = strtolower($contenturl);
               $category = clean_string($_POST['category']);

                 // Make sure they selected a category
                if ($category == 0){
                $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Please select a category</div>";
                   header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
                   exit; 
               }

       // Check to see if have backlink and nofollow atribute
       $parse = parse_url($contenturl);
       $base_url = $parse["host"]; // domain.com

       $linkback1 = reciprocal_linkback($contenturl, "http://www.dumpvid.com", 1);

       if ("$linkback1"=="0") {


       $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Backlink was not found, or nofollow detected.</div> ";
       header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
        exit; 

       }

       // Check to see if have backlink in the main also
       $parse = parse_url($contenturl);
       $base_url = $parse["host"]; // domain.com

       $linkback2 = reciprocal_linkback($base_url, "http://www.dumpvid.com", 1);

       if ("$linkback2"=="0") {


       $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Backlink found only on content url.</div> ";
       header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
        exit; 

       }

               // Check if TITLE and URL are filled in
               if (empty($contenttitle) || $contenttitle == "Title?"){
                $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Please Fill In Title</div>";
                   header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
                   exit; 
               }

               elseif (empty($contenturl) || $contenttitle == "http://"){
                $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b>Invalid URL</div>";
                   header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
                   exit; 
               }
               elseif (empty($contentdescription) || $contentdescription == "Nice description gets more traffic..."){
                $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Invalid or Missing Descriptio</div>";
                   header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
                   exit; 
               }


               // Check if VALID URL
               if (is_url("$contenturl")) {     
               } else { 
                   $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Doesn't seem to be a valid URL</div>";
                   header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
                   exit; 
               }
```

The structure of the validation file is basically this, if you need me to post the whole validation file and the form please let me know.

I just want to keep the field values the user filled before in case the validation fails.

Answer (score 1):

You should display form again on error but without using `header('Location:...')` because you will lost params sent using form after redirect. You may use function for retriving params in html:

```
function getParam($name, $defaultVal = null){
    return isset($_REQUEST[$name]) ? $_REQUEST[$name] : $defaultVal;
}


<input type="text" value="<?php echo getParam('firstname', ''); ?>" name="firstname">
```

**EDIT**

If you have 2 files:
`form.php` - your form definition
`save_form.php` - form validation,

Then in `save_form.php` you could use something like this:

```
//...
if($error){
    include 'form.php';
    die();
}
```

and in form.php

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo getParam('firstname', ''); ?>" name="firstname">
```

Comment: hi piotrekkr you might be right, and thats why nothing works on my form, can you tell me what should i use instead of header location on my validation file? thanks PS your function havent work either

Comment: Check my post again. My function should work when you don't use redirect to show form.

Comment: its not workin because i dont know how to avoid header location redirect :S

Answer (score 0):

As i understand i think you have to do this in html like:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['firstname'])) ? $_REQUEST['firstname'] : ''; ?>" name="firstname">
```

this will return you that you want.. Apply something like this to all fields..

**EDIT:** the above will work when you will click on the submit button then you will get the 'firstname' value else it will show blank.. And Please Never forget to validate on the above of the `<form>` tag means at the top of the page..

Comment: thanks jogesh_p i will give it a try and try to play around with that example, im a begginer and i just noticed that php is a world, there are some areas on it that i dont understand.

Comment: @DaniQueiroga Don't worry about the problems, Stackoverflow is the right place to solving the problems,,

Comment: i have used your code, and changed the firstname value to contenttitle wich is the name of the title input, and it trow me this error: e error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in... do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: im at the office right now but i will check this with more time later when i get home.

Comment: @DaniQueiroga, Thanks to make me correct now check the code and apply,  :)

Comment: Thanks jogesh_p but i might have to do something else, because noting happens, it just dont display the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

//save post values into session
if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post'){
    $_SESSION['_postHistory'] = $_POST;
}


//this will restore your previously posted values into $_POST global
if(isset($_SESSION['_postHistory']) && is_array($_SESSION['_postHistory'])){
   foreach($_SESSION['_postHistory'] as $key => $val){
      if(!isset($_POST[$key])) $_POST[$key] = $val;
   }
}

function getPostValue($key, $default = null){
   return (isset($_POST[$key])) ? $_POST[$key] : $default;
}
?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo getPostValue('fieldname')?>" name="fieldname"/>
```

I don't recommend using $_REQUEST for post as you might have the same param defined in $_GET as well which can conflict each other.

Comment: hi rbncha thanks for your reply, i used your code but it trows me the folow error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']' in....... on line 5

Comment: Yeah! there were typo... I have edited it. Did you check it ?